# I keep getting a error spammed in the log of the non master client in unity photon pun

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

This error keeps getting spammed in the console:

```
(Filename: C:/Users/Finalbi/Documents/Stocks and Shares/Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs Line: 360)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at GameManager.Gameover (PlayerScore[] scores) [0x0002d] in C:\Users\Finalbi\Documents\Stocks and Shares\Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs:360 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <605bf8b31fcb444b85176da963870aa7>:0 
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00083] in <605bf8b31fcb444b85176da963870aa7>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <605bf8b31fcb444b85176da963870aa7>:0 
  at Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.ExecuteRpc (ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable rpcData, Photon.Realtime.Player sender) [0x005d6] in C:\Users\Finalbi\Documents\Stocks and Shares\Assets\Photon\PhotonUnityNetworking\Code\PhotonNetworkPart.cs:554 
  at Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.OnEvent (ExitGames.Client.Photon.EventData photonEvent) [0x000ac] in C:\Users\Finalbi\Documents\Stocks and Shares\Assets\Photon\PhotonUnityNetworking\Code\PhotonNetworkPart.cs:2202 
  at Photon.Realtime.LoadBalancingClient.OnEvent (ExitGames.Client.Photon.EventData photonEvent) [0x0052e] in C:\Users\Finalbi\Documents\Stocks and Shares\Assets\Photon\PhotonRealtime\Code\LoadBalancingClient.cs:3362 
  at ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase.DeserializeMessageAndCallback (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream) [0x002e4] in D:\Dev\Work\photon-dotnet-sdk\PhotonDotNet\PeerBase.cs:904 
  at ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer.DispatchIncomingCommands () [0x003d2] in D:\Dev\Work\photon-dotnet-sdk\PhotonDotNet\EnetPeer.cs:577 
  at ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer.DispatchIncomingCommands () [0x00038] in D:\Dev\Work\photon-dotnet-sdk\PhotonDotNet\PhotonPeer.cs:1771 
  at Photon.Pun.PhotonHandler.Dispatch () [0x00030] in C:\Users\Finalbi\Documents\Stocks and Shares\Assets\Photon\PhotonUnityNetworking\Code\PhotonHandler.cs:232 
Rethrow as AggregateException: Caught 5 exception(s) in methods called by DispatchIncomingCommands(). Rethrowing first only (see above). (Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.)
  at Photon.Pun.PhotonHandler.Dispatch () [0x00098] in C:\Users\Finalbi\Documents\Stocks and Shares\Assets\Photon\PhotonUnityNetworking\Code\PhotonHandler.cs:250 
  at Photon.Pun.PhotonHandler.FixedUpdate () [0x00012] in C:\Users\Finalbi\Documents\Stocks and Shares\Assets\Photon\PhotonUnityNetworking\Code\PhotonHandler.cs:152
```

This is my gameManager script:

```
using ExitGames.Client.Photon;
using Photon.Pun;
using Hashtable = ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Linq;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public GameObject Main;
    public GameObject c1;
    public GameObject c2;
    public GameObject c3;
    public GameObject c4;
    public GameObject c5;
    public GameObject c6;

    public TextMeshProUGUI ctext1;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ctext2;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ctext3;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ctext4;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ctext5;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ctext6;

    public TextMeshProUGUI cdtext1;
    public TextMeshProUGUI cdtext2;
    public TextMeshProUGUI cdtext3;
    public TextMeshProUGUI cdtext4;
    public TextMeshProUGUI cdtext5;
    public TextMeshProUGUI cdtext6;

    public TextMeshProUGUI MoneyIndcater;
    public TextMeshProUGUI TimeIndcater;
    public TextMeshProUGUI StocksIndcater1;
    public TextMeshProUGUI StocksIndacter2;
    public TextMeshProUGUI StocksIndacter3;
    public TextMeshProUGUI StocksIndacter4;
    public TextMeshProUGUI StocksIndacter5;
    public TextMeshProUGUI StocksIndacter6;
    public TextMeshProUGUI PriceIndacter1;
    public TextMeshProUGUI PriceIndacter2;
    public TextMeshProUGUI PriceIndacter3;
    public TextMeshProUGUI PriceIndacter4;
    public TextMeshProUGUI PriceIndacter5;
    public TextMeshProUGUI PriceIndacter6;
    public GameObject BankruptIndacter1;
    public GameObject BankruptIndacter2;
    public GameObject BankruptIndacter3;
    public GameObject BankruptIndacter4;
    public GameObject BankruptIndacter5;
    public GameObject BankruptIndacter6;

    public Company company1;
    public Company company2;
    public Company company3;
    public Company company4;
    public Company company5;
    public Company company6;

    public int maxDays = 10;
    public int days = 1;
    public Dictionary<int, int> Stocks;
    public List<Company> CompanysInUse;

    public bool lastDay = false;
    public bool gameOver = false;
    public bool sentScore = false;

    public bool greenLight = false;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> greenLightTaskCompletionSource;
    public int forwardVotes = 0;
    public List<Player> playersVoted;

    public TextMeshProUGUI voteText;

    public List<PlayerScore> playersScores;

    PhotonView view;

    public int money;


    public GameObject leaderboard;
    public TextMeshProUGUI leaderboardtext;
    public GameObject fowardTimeButton;

    // Start is called before the first frame update


    void Start()
    {
        sentScore = false;
        gameOver = false;
        lastDay = false;
        view = PhotonView.Get(this);
        playersScores = new List<PlayerScore>();
        playersVoted = new List<Player>();
        money = 10;
        days = 1;
        forwardVotes = 0;
        greenLightTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        Stocks = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        Stocks[1] = 0;
        Stocks[2] = 0;
        Stocks[3] = 0;
        Stocks[4] = 0;
        Stocks[5] = 0;
        Stocks[6] = 0;
        voteText.text = forwardVotes + "/" + PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount;
        CompanysInUse = new List<Company>();
        Companies companies1 = new Companies();
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                int random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, companies1.companies.Count);
                Company company = companies1.companies[random];
                company.price = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
                CompanysInUse.Add(company);

            }
            company1 = CompanysInUse[0];
            company2 = CompanysInUse[1];
            company3 = CompanysInUse[2];
            company4 = CompanysInUse[3];
            company5 = CompanysInUse[4];
            company6 = CompanysInUse[5];
            view.RPC("SetCompanysClient", RpcTarget.All, company1, company2, company3, company4, company5, company6);
        }




    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        PhotonPeer.RegisterType(typeof(Company), (byte)'A', Company.Serialize, Company.Deserialize);
        PhotonPeer.RegisterType(typeof(PlayerScore), (byte)'B', PlayerScore.Serialize, PlayerScore.Deserialize);
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MoneyIndcater.text = "Money: " + money;
        TimeIndcater.text = "Days: " + days;
        StocksIndcater1.text = "Stocks: " + Stocks[1];
        StocksIndacter2.text = "Stocks: " + Stocks[2];
        StocksIndacter3.text = "Stocks: " + Stocks[6];
        StocksIndacter4.text = "Stocks: " + Stocks[4];
        StocksIndacter5.text = "Stocks: " + Stocks[5];
        StocksIndacter6.text = "Stocks: " + Stocks[6];
        PriceIndacter1.text = "Price: " + company1.price;
        PriceIndacter2.text = "Price: " + company2.price;
        PriceIndacter3.text = "Price: " + company3.price;
        PriceIndacter4.text = "Price: " + company4.price;
        PriceIndacter5.text = "Price: " + company5.price;
        PriceIndacter6.text = "Price: " + company6.price;
        BankruptIndacter1.SetActive(company1.bankrupt);
        BankruptIndacter2.SetActive(company2.bankrupt);
        BankruptIndacter3.SetActive(company3.bankrupt);
        BankruptIndacter4.SetActive(company4.bankrupt);
        BankruptIndacter5.SetActive(company5.bankrupt);
        BankruptIndacter6.SetActive(company6.bankrupt);
        voteText.text = forwardVotes + "/" + PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount;
        if (forwardVotes >= PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount && PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            view.RPC("FowardTime", RpcTarget.All);
        }
        if (gameOver && !sentScore)
        {
            sentScore = true;
            view.RPC("SendScore", RpcTarget.MasterClient, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer, money);
        }
        if (playersScores.Count >= PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount && PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient && gameOver)
        {
            playersScores.Sort(new PlayerScoreComparer());
            view.RPC("Gameover", RpcTarget.All, playersScores.ToArray() as object);
        }
    }








    public void onPressBuy(int CompanyNumber)
    {
        int UCompanyNumber = CompanyNumber + 1;
        Company companyBuyingFrom = null;
        switch (UCompanyNumber)
        {

            case 1: companyBuyingFrom = company1; break;
            case 2: companyBuyingFrom = company2; break;
            case 3: companyBuyingFrom = company3; break;
            case 4: companyBuyingFrom = company4; break;
            case 5: companyBuyingFrom = company5; break;
            case 6: companyBuyingFrom = company6; break;

        }
        if (companyBuyingFrom.price <= money && !companyBuyingFrom.bankrupt && !lastDay)
        {
            switch (UCompanyNumber)
            {

                case 1: money = money - company1.price; break;
                case 2: money = money - company2.price; break;
                case 3: money = money - company3.price; break;
                case 4: money = money - company4.price; break;
                case 5: money = money - company5.price; break;
                case 6: money = money - company6.price; break;

            }
            Stocks[CompanyNumber + 1]++;
        }
    }

    public void onPressSell(int CompanyNumber)
    {
        int UCompanyNumber = CompanyNumber + 1;
        if (Stocks[CompanyNumber + 1] >= 1)
        {
            Stocks[CompanyNumber + 1]--;
            switch (UCompanyNumber) 
            {

                case 1: money = money + company1.price; break;
                case 2: money = money + company2.price; break;
                case 3: money = money + company3.price; break;
                case 4: money = money + company4.price; break;
                case 5: money = money + company5.price; break;
                case 6: money = money + company6.price; break;

            }
                
        }
    }

    public void OnPressForwardTime()
    {
        view.RPC("VoteForwardTime", RpcTarget.MasterClient, PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer);
    }
    [PunRPC]
    public void FowardTime()
    {
        forwardVotes = 0;
        playersVoted.Clear();
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
        {
            if (days == 1)
            {
                foreach (Company company in CompanysInUse)
                {
                    int increaseAmount = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 5);
                    company.price += increaseAmount;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Company company in CompanysInUse)
                {
                    if (!company.bankrupt)
                    {
                        int increaseAmount = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-10, 10);
                        company.price += increaseAmount;
                        company.bankrupt = company.price <= 0;
                        if (company.bankrupt)
                        {
                            company.price = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            company1 = CompanysInUse[0];
            company2 = CompanysInUse[1];
            company3 = CompanysInUse[2];
            company4 = CompanysInUse[3];
            company5 = CompanysInUse[4];
            company6 = CompanysInUse[5];
            view.RPC("SetCompanysClient", RpcTarget.All, company1, company2, company3, company4, company5, company6);

        }
        
        days++;
        if (days == maxDays)
        {
            lastDay = true;
        }
        if (days > maxDays)
        {
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }
    [PunRPC]
    public void SetCompanysClient(Company company1, Company company2, Company company3, Company company4, Company company5, Company company6)
    {
        this.company1 = company1;
        this.company2 = company2;
        this.company3 = company3;
        this.company4 = company4;
        this.company5 = company5;
        this.company6 = company6;
        ctext1.text = company1.name;
        ctext2.text = company2.name;
        ctext3.text = company3.name;
        ctext4.text = company4.name;
        ctext5.text = company5.name;
        ctext6.text = company6.name;

        cdtext1.text = company1.description;
        cdtext2.text = company2.description;
        cdtext3.text = company3.description;
        cdtext4.text = company4.description;
        cdtext5.text = company5.description;
        cdtext6.text = company6.description;
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void VoteForwardTime(Player player)
    {
        if (playersVoted.Contains(player))
        {
            forwardVotes--;
            playersVoted.Remove(player);
            return;
        }
        forwardVotes++;
        playersVoted.Add(player);
        view.RPC("sentVotes", RpcTarget.All, forwardVotes);
    }
    [PunRPC]
    public void SendScore(Player player, int score)
    {
        PlayerScore playerscore = new PlayerScore(score, player);
        playersScores.Add(playerscore);
    }
    [PunRPC]
    public void Gameover(PlayerScore[] scores)
    {
        playersScores = scores.ToList();
        StringBuilder leaderboardStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int postion = 1;
        foreach (PlayerScore score in playersScores)
        {
            leaderboardStringBuilder.Append(postion + ": " + score.player.NickName + ": " + score.score + "\n");
            postion++;
        }
        leaderboardtext.text = leaderboardStringBuilder.ToString();
        MoneyIndcater.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        TimeIndcater.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        voteText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        fowardTimeButton.SetActive(false);
        Main.SetActive(false);
        c1.SetActive(false);
        c2.SetActive(false);
        c3.SetActive(false);
        c4.SetActive(false);
        c5.SetActive(false);
        c6.SetActive(false);
        leaderboard.SetActive(true);

    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void sentVotes(int fowardVotes)
    {
        forwardVotes = fowardVotes;
    }

























    public void OnClickBack()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Lobby");
    }



    public void Back()
    {
        c1.SetActive(false);
        c2.SetActive(false);
        c3.SetActive(false);
        c4.SetActive(false);
        c5.SetActive(false);    
        c6.SetActive(false);
        Main.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void swapToC1() 
    { 
        Main.SetActive(false);
        c1.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void swapToC2() 
    {
        Main.SetActive(false);
        c2.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void swapToC3() 
    {
        Main.SetActive(false);
        c3.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void swapToC4() 
    {
        Main.SetActive(false);
        c4.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void swapToC5() 
    {
        Main.SetActive(false);
        c5.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void swapToC6() 
    {
        Main.SetActive(false);
        c6.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Line 360 is: `leaderboardStringBuilder.Append(postion + ": " + score.player.NickName + ": " + score.score + "\n");`

In the gameover rpc I can't understand this error and why it would be caused by this line this error is triggerd when the game ends and gameover rpc is called

I havent tried anything except trying to
decypher the error.

Here is the playerScore class:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using Photon.Realtime;
    using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Impl;
    using Photon.Pun;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    
    public class PlayerScore : IPunObservable
    {
        public int score;
        public Player player;
        
        public PlayerScore(int score, Player player)
        {
            this.score = score;
            this.player = player;
        }
    
        public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
        {
            if (stream.IsWriting)
            {
                stream.SendNext(player.ActorNumber);
                stream.SendNext(score);
            }
            else if (stream.IsReading)
            {
                player = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.GetPlayer((int)stream.ReceiveNext());
                score = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
            }
    
        }
    
        public static byte[] Serialize(object customType)
        {
            PlayerScore playerScore = (PlayerScore)customType;
            return new byte[] { (byte)playerScore.player.ActorNumber, (byte)playerScore.score };
        }
    
        public static object Deserialize(byte[] data)
        {
            return new PlayerScore(data[0], PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.GetPlayer(data[1]));
        }
    }
    
    public class PlayerScoreComparer : IComparer<PlayerScore>
    {
        public int Compare(PlayerScore x, PlayerScore y)
        {
            return x.score.CompareTo(y.score);
        }
    }
```

Comment: One reason the error could be occurring if the player does not have a nickname.  But I do not think this is the case.  The exception says "Invoke" which usually indicates a cross thread issue.  Where is GameOver() method called.  It is not in the code posted.

Comment: gameover is called as a rpc so here: view.RPC("Gameover", RpcTarget.All, playersScores.ToArray() as object); in the update method

Comment: Are you sure that `player` is being populated on the receiving end?  How is `PlayerScore` defined?

Comment: the rpc sendScore gets exucuted on the master by all clients and then then gameover runs on all clients the master basicly collects all the scores and players and sends them to all the clients so they can make a leaderboard

Comment: Where do you stop Update when game is finished?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Update always runs

Comment: Can you show us your implemention of `PlayerScore`? Are you sure it is a type supported by Photon's RPC serialization? spoiler: it is most probably not => you will most probably have to provide explicit serialization and deserialization methods for it. See https://doc.photonengine.com/pun/current/reference/serialization-in-photon and in specific the section `Custom Types In C#`

Comment: i added the player score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out you need to replace player with a string to hold the nickname thank you everyone for helping